# How to automatically install root certificate on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, certificate

I have a project useed https.So I use the openssl Generation a root certificate!just likc CA
.So when I visited the asp.net by my website.The IE ask me the certificate is not Legitimate。
I must Click The Browser input box to install the root certificate!
But that's not good for Client.
SO I want to know Is there hava any script automatically install root certificate。
                                                         Thanks

Comment: No, and it's fortunate. Ssl rely on trust and trust authority. If a web site can self-add ssl certificates on the browser, the whole system fails. Either buy a certificate from a known trusted authority or accept to have this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible. And that's a good thing. If you could force a client to auto-accept/-install a certificate, the whole concept of SSL would become flawed.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/01/28/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-javascript.aspx    I find a Method in this page,but the code is wrong.is anyone know how to do it thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible because of security reasons, the best you can do is obtain a certificate from an official certificate authority.